# Is there a more elegant way to convert an XML Document to a String in Java than this code?

Tags: java, xml

Here is the code currently used.

```
public String getStringFromDoc(org.w3c.dom.Document doc)    {
        try
        {
           DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
           StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
           TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
           Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
           transformer.transform(domSource, result);
           writer.flush();
           return writer.toString();
        }
        catch(TransformerException ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Relies on [DOM Level3 Load/Save](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-LS/load-save.html):

```
public String getStringFromDoc(org.w3c.dom.Document doc)    {
    DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
    LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();
    return lsSerializer.writeToString(doc);   
}
```

Comment: Has Java 7 provided another alternative?

Comment: import import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;

Answer (score 14):

The transformer API is the only XML-standard way to transform from a DOM object to a serialized form (String in this case). As standard I mean SUN [Java XML API for XML Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing).

Other alternatives such as Xerces [XMLSerializer](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xml/serialize/XMLSerializer.html) or JDOM [XMLOutputter](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html) are more direct methods (less code) but they are framework-specific.

In my opinion the way you have used is the most elegant and most portable of all. By using a standard XML Java API you can plug the XML-Parser or XML-Transformer of your choice without changing the code(the same as JDBC drivers). Is there anything more elegant than that?

Answer (score 14):

This is a little more concise:

```
try {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return result.getWriter().toString();
} catch(TransformerException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Otherwise you could use a library like XMLSerializer from Apache:

```
//Serialize DOM
OutputFormat format    = new OutputFormat (doc); 
// as a String
StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter ();    
XMLSerializer serial   = new XMLSerializer (stringOut,format);
serial.serialize(doc);
// Display the XML
System.out.println(stringOut.toString());
```

Comment: I like the second variant. With JRE 1.8.0 `XMLSerializer` is even part of `rt.jar`

Answer (score 9):

You could use [XOM](http://xom.nu/):

```
org.w3c.dom.Document domDocument = ...;
nu.xom.Document xomDocument = 
    nu.xom.converters.DOMConverter.convert(domDocument);
String xml = xomDocument.toXML();
```

You could use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/):

```
org.jsoup.helper.W3CDom converter = new W3CDom();
String html = converter.asString( domDocument );
```

Comment: +1, XOM (and other similar libraries) can really simplify matters.