# XML Document to String

Tags: java, xml, string, dom, xmldocument

What's the simplest way to get the String representation of a XML Document (`org.w3c.dom.Document`)? That is all nodes will be on a single line.

As an example, from

```
<root>
  <a>trge</a>
  <b>156</b>
</root>
```

(this is only a tree representation, in my code it's a `org.w3c.dom.Document` object, so I can't treat it as a String)

to

```
"<root> <a>trge</a> <b>156</b> </root>"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315517/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-convert-an-xml-document-to-a-string-in-java-than

Comment: http://iandjava.blogspot.in/2013/06/java-string-to-document-and-document-to.html

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Assuming `doc` is your instance of `org.w3c.dom.Document`:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
String output = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");
```

Comment: the `replaceAll` is probably not necessary if you add another output property: `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");`

Comment: and the `writer.getBuffer().toString()` can just be `writer.toString()`

Comment: @bvdb both excellent points. There is an extra advantage to explicitly adding the `OutputKeys.INDENT` line, because then you can also set it to `"yes"` to keep the whitespace--if that's what you want (in my situation I've found that just removing `replaceAll` did not work to include the whitespace in the string).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384802/java-how-to-indent-xml-generated-by-transformer for an explanation of how to get the indent to work properly

Answer (score 2):

Use the Apache XMLSerializer

here's an example:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.asp?p=31349&seqNum=3&rl=1

you can check this as well

http://www.netomatix.com/XmlFileToString.aspx

Comment: Xerces is still, ridiculously, not officially distributing via Maven (thus groovy too), including no reliable source or JavaDocs, WTF!
No official maven support makes deprecation resolution harder, makes consistent updates more hassle, and poses security risks, so it is stupid to have any dependencies on it now!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get rid of all newline characters in all your text nodes. Then you can use an identity transform to output your DOM tree. Look at the javadoc for `TransformerFactory#newTransformer()`.