# HashMap to XML syntax

Tags: java

Am looking in plain old java code where we can convert hashmap to xml and xml to hashmap

```
<key1>value1</key1>
<key2>value2</key2>
```

with out using any external libraries

any info or some light will help. Thanks

Comment: Why won't you use a perfectly suited library like XStream?

Comment: That's not XML - it needs a single root level element in order to be well-formed. Also are you certain that all your keys are legal xml element names (no spaces, no illegal punctuation, none of them start with a digit, etc.)? A safer representation would be `<entry key="key1">value1</entry>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code where I used `Pattern` and `Matcher` to find the key and value from the xml string.

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM4sZ4/1) for regex pattern.

Here is better picture of the regex pattern

```
<([^>]+)>([^<]*)<\/\1>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jeaowUAahq0m2P4X)

I have used parenthesis `(...)` for grouping and `\1` is used for back reference of the first matched group.

---

sample code:

```
String xml = "<key1>value1</key1><key2>value2</key2>";

// ------------------------- XML to Map -----------

Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>([^<]*)</\\1>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);
while (m.find()) {
    map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
}

// ------------------------- Map to XML -----------

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    buffer.append("<").append(entry.getKey()).append(">");
    buffer.append(entry.getValue());
    buffer.append("</").append(entry.getKey()).append(">");
}
System.out.println(buffer);
```

output:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
<key1>value1</key1><key2>value2</key2>
```

---

Here is good way to convert XML into Map using `DOM parser` API. It's better explained in Oracle tutorial on ***[Reading XML Data into a DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)*** along with lots of good example.

**Note:** I have added a root node to make it well-formed xml string.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

String xml = "<root><key1>value1</key1><key2>value2</key2></root>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));

Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    map.put(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName(), nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0)
            .getNodeValue());
}
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456680/xml-document-to-string)

Comment: Thanks Braj, i used as above and i see my xml with   &lt;KeyAuditIndicator&gt;&lt;

Comment: replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&gp;` with `>` or do vice verse.

Comment: @JimGarrison I agree with you but as per OP requirement (without using external libraries) I shared an alternative for small xml fragment.

Comment: Please share your thoughts if you don't like the answer so that I can improve it again for everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For writing-

```
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName,false);
    BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        buffWriter.write("<" + entry.getKey() + ">");
        buffWriter.write(entry.getValue());
        buffWriter.write("</" + entry.getKey() + ">");
        buffWriter.newLine();
        // ...
    }
    buffWriter.flush();
    buffWriter.close();
```