# How do I read XML string from file into a String?

Tags: android, xml, file-read

I have an XML file stored in the SD card. It contains data like this:

```
<employees>
    <emp id="1" sex="male">
        <name>John</name>
        <age>36</age>
    </emp>
    <emp id="2" sex="female">
        <name>Marry</name>
        <age>28</age>
    </emp>
    <emp id="3" sex="male">
        <name>Phil</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </emp>
    <emp id="4" sex="male">
        <name>Frank</name>
        <age>33</age>
    </emp>
</employees>
```

I want convert it to string, like `String str = "xml data".`

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert XML to JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823264/quickest-way-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

Comment: no , I just want convert data from xml to string

Comment: Please take a peek at the question

Comment: your XML is a String. It does not need to be converted.

Comment: how to get it like String str = "xml data"

Comment: You need to open it with an XML document reader if you want the semantic content, but if you just want to read the string from a file then you just need a file reader which is dependent on your programming language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Document to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456680/xml-document-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open it with an XML document reader if you want the semantic content, but if you just want to read the string from a file then you just need a file reader which is dependent on your programming language.

For example in C# it would be `File.ReadAllLines("myfile.xml")`.