# How do I write a DOM Document to File?

Tags: java, file, dom, file-io, domdocument

How do I write this `document` to the local filesystem?

```
public void docToFile(org.w3c.dom.Document document, URI path) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(path);
}
```

I need to iterate the `document`, or might there be a "to xml/html/string" method?  I was looking at:

`document.getXmlEncoding();`

Not [quite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getXmlEncoding()) what I'm after -- but something like that.  Looking for the `String` representation and then to write that to file like:

```
Path file = ...;
byte[] buf = ...;
Files.write(file, buf);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Document to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456680/xml-document-to-string)

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a duplicate, but the answer from ipsa is simpler than the linked answer.

Comment: It's almost a complete copy except for some of the usual Java related IO nonsense but OK :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a transformer class to convert the DOM content to an xml file, something like below:

```
Document doc =...

// write the content into xml file

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("/tmp/output.xml"));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I hope this ends up working for you!