# LSSerializer vs Transformer for serializing xml to String

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have to turn a org.w3c.dom.Document into a java.lang.String.  I have found two possible approaches, one using org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer and the other using a  javax.xml.transform.Transformer.  I have samples of each below.

Can anyone tell me which method is to be preferred?

```
public String docToStringUsingLSSerializer(org.w3c.dom.Document doc) {
    DOMImplementationRegistry reg = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
    DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) reg.getDOMImplementation("LS");
    LSSerializer serializer = impl.createLSSerializer();
    return serializer.writeToString(doc);
}

public String docToStringUsingTransformer(org.w3c.dom.Document doc) {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();  
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw));  
    return stw.toString();
}
```

Comment: have you found an answer by any chance by now? I have wondered the same question myself.

Comment: I didn't get any answers, and couldn't find any articles preferring one or the other.  However, nearly all the articles and posts I found on the serializing a String use javax.xml.Transform, so it seems to be the overall preferred approach.  In spite of that I went with  org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer, and I don't have any solid reason to give for it.  I just like the feel of the "One Stop Shopping" I get the by using the org.w3c.dom packages.  So far I have nothing negative to report by using this method.  So I think my answer is "They both seem ok".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several points to consider:

1. *LSSerializer* is usually considered faster than *Transformer*.
2. Nevertheless it heavily depends on the implementation. A *Transformer* based on SAX will have good performance. And there are different implementors (Xalan, Xerces, ...).
3. It is very easy to check which is better in your system. Design a simple test case with a complex XML. Run it in a loop thousdns of time, wrap that with time check (Syste.getCurrentMilliseconds or something) and you've got yourself an answer.
4. Other nice answers include:

   - [Is there a more elegant way to convert an XML Document to a String in Java than this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315517/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-convert-an-xml-document-to-a-string-in-java-than)
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137488/ways-of-producing-xml-in-java

Comment: Thanks for your illuminating answer.  Another issue that concerns me is what I call "Abandonment Likelihood", the likelihood that a creator of a library or API might abandon it, no longer offering updates as the underlying technology (in this case the JDK) changes.  Do you think either has a higher likelihood of being abandoned or deprecated? Thanks