# File saved in internal storage is not being preserved

Tags: android, internal-storage

I am trying to save an xml file into Android's internal storage. However, the file is not getting preserved. Every time I restart the emulator, the file would be empty. The file would only get stuff written to it when  I manually choose to write stuff to it within the app. Then, if I close the app or whatever, the file contents get preserved. However, when I shutdown the emulator, the file would be there, but empty.

Therefore, I am not sure if I am correctly saving it.

Please take a look at my code, maybe there is something wrong with it or its some setting with my Android emulator.

```
public static void store(Context c, String filename, int width, int height, int rooms, int expected_partiters, BSPNode root, Cells cells, int[][] dists, int startX, int startY)
{
     try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();


            // root elements
            storeMaze(width, height, rooms, expected_partiters, root, cells, dists, startX, startY, doc);

            String serializedDoc = MazeFileWriter.getStringFromDoc(doc);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput("data_test.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(serializedDoc.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
         pce.printStackTrace();
     }
}

static String getStringFromDoc(org.w3c.dom.Document doc) {
    try
    {
       DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
       TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
       transformer.transform(domSource, result);
       writer.flush();
       return writer.toString();
    }
    catch(TransformerException ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```

I am a beginner at Android, so any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a StringWriter on the read part if I am understanding your code correctly. I think you want a StringReader.

If that was not what you are trying to do there (read), I can look further, that was just what caught my eye.

Comment: The file was written to correctly, I checked the file contents manually through Android's DDMS. However, the problem is the file not getting preserved when I power off the emulator. After power off, the file would be empty. Could this be the reason?

Comment: The getStringFromDoc method is not reading, but writing... so it would never return anything. Swap to read and see what it gives you.

Comment: If you are actually reading correctly before the emulator is stopped, check your settings that the emulator is not set to reset user data on each load.

Comment: I was using the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356258/how-do-i-convert-a-org-w3c-dom-document-object-to-a-string

Comment: Ok, I found the problem and it was really really dumb. I would click the "x" on the emulator without properly shutting the emulator down via the power button. Sigh, sorry for your time.

Comment: :) Happens to the best of us. Glad you found it!