# Java XML modifying

Tags: java, xml

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class modifyXML {

    public static void modify(StringBuffer XMLBuffer) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();   
        Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(XMLBuffer.toString().getBytes()));
        Element rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList priceList = rootNode.getElementsByTagName("price");
        priceList.item(0).setTextContent("190");

        NodeList inStockList = rootNode.getElementsByTagName("id_product_attribute");
        inStockList.item(0).setTextContent("100");



    }
}
```

I am trying to modify an XML file and then put it all back together. I have managed with the modifying part, but I can not get the XML file back together. The result can be either a String or a StringBuffer.

What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: Whats the relevance of your code? Your question doesn't refer to it at all...

Comment: Lateral suggestion: use a less idiotic XML API that doesn't bury this functionality, like JDOM. (No, I'm not a fan of the standard DOM.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  a `Transformer` as described by [WhiteFang34](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653230/whitefang34) in [XML Document to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456836/664577).

Official Java Tutorials: [Writing Out a DOM as an XML File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html) (just make `StreamResult` Wrap something else such as `StringWriter`).

**Update:**

[Less known, shorter alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315663/664577) by [ykaganovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10026/ykaganovich) based on Load / Save objects:

Comment: For pretty printed XML (indentation) look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java). Look not at the chosen answer but with `TransformerFactory`.

Comment: Post by WhiteFang was pretty clear and straight-forward, I recommend that. Thank you for your answer.