# outer and innerHTML with org.w3c.dom API

Tags: java, html, dom

I am using org.w3c.dom APIs to parse a a HTML fragment which is composed of a series of

tags with various markups in between. I am trying to ingest the HTML fragment into a org.w3c.dom.Document and splitting on the HTML into the `<p>..</p>`

I can easily get a NodeList of the `<p>` tags (`doc.getElementsByTagName("p")`) however from the NodeList I am having trouble getting the equivalent of "innerHTML" and "outerHTML" of the elements in the NodeList.

How can i get the equivalent of innerHTML and outerHTML w the org.w3c.dom APIs? (I dont want to introduce another dependency such as JSoup)

Answer (score 1):

[inner/outerHTML](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/innerhtml/raw-file/tip/index.html#extensions-to-the-element-interface) are just convenience methods which essentially serialize document fragments to/from strings through DOM parsers and serializers.
You can achieve the same results "by foot" by using the [DOM Load/Save APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/package-summary.html)

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315663/1362755) how to use them.

Comment: ... and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948326) for specific examples of using DOM Load/Save APIs for this task