# XML External Entity Injection: Hp Fortify issue in java 1.6

Tags: java, security, owasp, xxe, application-security

I was trying to fix XEE issue and have tried other options but won't work. Would be great if there were any pointers.

Below is my code snippet..

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(feed);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource,outputTarget);
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479324/prevent-xxe-fortify-issue-for-trasnformerfactory?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OWASP XXE Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

based of what i see in your code, you should modifiy it like this :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(feed);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");

tf.newTransformer().transform(xmlSource,outputTarget);
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. let me try this

Comment: This won't work in the version of Java mentioned (1.6) as those constants were not implemented until Java 7. The best solution is to update to a supported version of Java.